# How to COUNT (*) WHERE column1 is >= The maximum value for specific value in column2?

Tags: sql

| title | duration |
| --- | --- |
| programme a | 1000 |
| programme b | 1500 |

I have a table like this, and I want to count all rows where the duration is at least 90% of the MAXIMUM duration of the programme in said row. How can I do this?

For context, each row is a play event, and duration is how long in seconds the play event lasted

Comment: could you please provide additional sample data and desired output

Comment: Some more comprehensive sample data and expected results would be useful.

Comment: Please share what have you tried so far and what problems you have. [so] is not a code generator service. Please read [ask] in [help]. Also please share which rdbms are you using.

Answer (score 3):

None of the other answers take into account, that the `MAX` should be calculated **per title** as per the *at least 90% of the MAXIMUM duration **of the programme** in said row* part of the original post.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  table T
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT title, MAX(duration) AS max_duration FROM table GROUP BY title)
  ) X
    ON T.title= X.title
WHERE
  T.duration >= X.max_duration * 0.9
```

I am assuming, that the `title` is unique (per programme) in the above, if not, replace that column with the correct identifier.

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table, (SELECT MAX(duration) AS m FROM your_table) AS sq 
WHERE duration/m >= 0.9
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH max_duration_by_title AS (SELECT title, MAX(duration) AS max_duration FROM your_table GROUP BY title)
SELECT base_table.title
, COUNT(1) AS total_plays
, COUNT (CASE WHEN base_table.duration >= 0.9 * max_duration.max_duration THEN 1 END) AS total_plays_longer_than_threshold
FROM your_table base_table
INNER JOIN max_duration_by_title
   ON base_table.title = max_duration_by_title.title
GROUP BY base_table.title
```

Comment: are you sure the OP's rdbms has CTE and CROSS JOIN support?

Comment: In 99% of cases they do, I'll roll the dice on it

Comment: MySql < v8 accounts for a lot more than 1% of the database community.